# Can I set a View's permission based on the viewing user's group membership?

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups

I have a view of user profiles configured as such.

[image]

However, I'd like to restrict this view to only members of the same group. Is this possible? How should I approach it?

Comment: Under PAGE SETTINGS, in Access: Permission <-- click on permission and see if there is an option there.

Comment: There is only options for the standard: User Role, OG Permission, and Permission. However, I'm not seeing how check for group membership that I'm specifying in the Contextual Filter

Comment: you would have to do this pro-grammatically. use **global user** to load the user group of the logedin user. The code for that you will have to figure out. Then you will need to grab the last `/%` from the url. Then all you need is an IF statement to compare the two, If it's true you embed the view usign `views_get_view()` [Embed Drupal Views Using PHP](http://lhmdesign.com/posts/embed-drupal-views-using-php)